# Can not pin MyComputer on windows 10 taskbar or as a tile

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, pin

I can not pin MyComputer to the taskbar when dragging it on the taskbar a list appears with the pinned system icons and in that list the MyComputer icon is there and seems pinned but it does not appear on the taskbar it self...

MyComputer also can't appear as a tile in the start menu.

OS is windows 10 Pro 64bit 1803

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your Taskbar, select Taskbar settings at the bottom, then select Themes from the elft, then click on Desktop Icons.

There you can manage icons for the desktop, Computer is the one you're looking for.

Comment: already done that it still doesnt pin on taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting, I found another way to pin the MyComputer to the taskbar.

Hope you like it.

1. Right-click the blank on the desktop
2. Click `New`-> `Shortcut`
3. Then type `explorer shell:MyComputerFolder` in location
4. Click Next, you will get a shortcut of MyComputer
5. Right-click the icon and click `Properties`, then you can `change the icon` as the same as the computer icon
6. Then in icon changer window, click `Browser` and find the path `C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll`.
7. Then select the icon, you want to use.
8. Finally, right-click the shortcut, and pin to the taskbar.

I have tested this, it works fine. Hope this can help you to **pin the MyComputer to the taskbar**.

[image]

[image]